# Button isn't displayed in RelativeLayout below GridView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the next problem: when a gridview content doesn't fit into device display and scrolling begins then a button below the gridview is not shown.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingLeft="16dp"
 android:paddingRight="16dp">

  <GridView
    android:id="@+id/generated_number_gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:columnWidth="90sp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10sp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10sp" />

  <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/generated_number_gridview"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="proceed"
    android:text="@string/proceed"
    android:textSize="25sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Would be very thankful for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this.**

**Just replace this with your XML code.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/generated_number_gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnProceed"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:columnWidth="90sp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10sp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnProceed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="proceed"
        android:text="Proceed"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is the Screen shot.**

[image]

Comment: @Kostya-OniL Check mark this as right answer thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from Button Layout properties.

```
        android:layout_below="@id/generated_number_gridview"
```

This means that It should be below the GridView. And your GridView size is not fixed. Since the renderer shows the GridView with multiple elements it fills the screen and your Button goes below that. That's why it's not visible.

I hope this is the UI that you are looking for.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/generated_number_gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnWidth="90sp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10sp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10sp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/proceedButton"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/proceedButton"
        android:onClick="proceed"
        android:text="proceed"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. Thanks a lot ! Just wanted to add that I also specified android:layout_alignParentTop="true" for GridView to process situation when this view is too small and doesn't fit parent start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this layout..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingLeft="16dp"
     android:paddingRight="16dp">

  <GridView
        android:id="@+id/generated_number_gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        **android:layout_above="@+id/btn_proceed"**
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:columnWidth="90sp"
        **android:horizontalSpacing="10dp**"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        **android:verticalSpacing="10dp"** />

 <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_proceed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="proceed"
        android:text="@string/proceed"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```